# should ResultSet be public

Tags: java, security

This already sounds like a stupid question but I was wondering if I have information that, it doesn't matter who sees it, is putting that info into a public ResultSet and passing that to another java class a terrible idea or just not good practice or either?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're asking about? It's hard to give you answers more specific than the "everything should be `private`!" platitudes without more information.

Comment: well it was more of a general question really. you know, what's the BEST practice.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but there's no simple answer to that question. There are a couple of well-accepted approaches to using databases in OOP languages: [DAOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). If you have a very simple program, though, just using JDBC directly in your program probably isn't a terrible idea. WRT your question specifically, OOP tells us you should probably wrap the `ResultSet` in another object with getters to access the values *inside* the `ResultSet` that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea because it doesn't work. A ResultSet is a reference to a database cursor, it's not a holder for information that you can pass around. Once you close the connection the resultSet will be invalid. Instead your Data Access Object should unpack the resultSet contents into some collection or Java Bean and pass that back.

Answer (score 2):

From what I read, in a MVC design, your database layer should avoid exposing database specific terms to the business logic layer (resultSet, SQLException, etc). I suggest you don't wrap resultSet and pass it around either. Dump the data from the resultSet in a DAO and give that to the business logic layer.